# SendGrid emails are going in junk folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, sendgrid

I am trying to send email using [sendgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid#hello-email) smpt relay

I have added and verified the domain **mydomain.com** over sendgrid and in DNS records also genearted the api key

Here is what I am trying

```
let sg = require('sendgrid');
let sendGrid = sg('my_api_key'),
            request = sendGrid.emptyRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                path: '/v3/mail/send',
                body: {
                    personalizations: [
                        {
                            to: [
                                {
                                    email: 'example@mydomain.com'
                                }
                            ],
                            subject: "Hi"
                        }
                    ],
                    from: {
                        email: 'example@mydomain.com'
                    },
                    content: [
                        {
                            type: 'text/html',
                            value: 'Hello'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        return sendGrid.API(request);
```

The API is giving me 202 status code and also emails are delivered but in the junk folder.

I am not getting why this is happening. Please suggest some help.

Comment: check whitelisting

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to your code, your code is successfully sending the messages.

You should review [SendGrid's documentation on Deliverability](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Undeliverable_Email/my_emails_are_going_to_spam.html).